# ASP.NET MVC unwanted values when binding dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need the action that receives the data as follows:
`/ContentPages/MyPage?id=1&param[test1]=testValue1&param[test2]=testValue2`

So, I wrote the action code and it works fine:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(int id, Dictionary<string, string> param)
{
  foreach (var pair in param)
  {
    //logger just prints string to file
    logger.Trace("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
  }
  return View();
}
```

With URL above it prints:

```
test1: testValue1
test2: testValue2
```

BUT when I don't pass any param (`/ContentPages/MyPage?id=1`) it prints:

```
controller: ContentPages
action: MyPage
```

Now I'm using the code:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(int id)
{
  foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
  {
     if (key.StartsWith("param["))
     {
         logger.Trace("{0}: {1}", key, Request.QueryString[key]);
     }
  }
  return View();
}
```

I want to understand what I'm doing wrong in first example?

Comment: Because its binding from the controllers `RouteData.Values` property (a `RouteValueDictionary`) which contains values for the controller and action names

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't say exactly why MVC Framework is binding to the action and controller values, I can suggest a way to get the behavior (I think) you want: add a `[FromQuery]` attribute to the parameter you want to model bind. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(int id, [FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> param)
```

This ensures that the model binding occurs specifically from the query string, and not from anywhere else (e.g. the request body, or - as I suspect happens when you don't include a query string - the route parameters).

Comment: Is that attribute applicable to mvc-5?

Comment: It works only for WebApi. Is there any MVC 5 alternative?

Comment: `[FromUri]`, maybe? I haven't used MVC5 in a while, so I'm a little rusty on what parts of the framework are available in what versions...